# What is the best way to estimate how much memory a row will require?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm working on a project that will have a single table holding lots and lots of rows on either a SQL Server or SQL Azure installation. I'm trying to estimate how many rows I can store per GB. Is it a matter of simply adding up the memory size of the individual column data types? Is there other overhead to consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Estimating the Size of a Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933068%28SQL.80%29.aspx) (SQL 2000).
- [Estimating the Size of a Clustered Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178085.aspx) (SQL 2005/2008)
- [Estimating the Size of a Nonclustered Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190620.aspx)  (SQL 2005/2008)
- [Estimating the Size of a Heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189124.aspx)  (SQL 2005/2008)

If you use Row Versioning, add 14 bytes per row, see [Row Versioning Resource Usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175492.aspx).

With SQL 2008 you should consider [Page Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280464.aspx).
With SQL 2008 R2 you need to also consider possibly [Unicode Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240835%28SQL.105%29.aspx).